# The collectionview cells shake up and down when used estimated values for a compositional layout and drag drop is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, nscollectionlayoutsection

1. Refer to ConferenceNewsFeedViewController in the attached project 2. Enable drag drop for collectionview
2. Increase the text/content in a few cells: refer ConferenceNewsController
   Result: The cells behave weird: move up and down when trying to drag drop. This happens if the cell heights are not identical and if estimated values are used in compositional layout. The shake still kicks in when the touch is stable and not moving.
3. Please refer image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSI1C.gif)
   Project link : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views

I tried with abosulte values and identical heights for cells and the shake effect is not observed. But in my case the cells heights need to be dynamic as the content is response based and there are stackviews, etc. I am interested in full width and dynamic height cells.